# How to pass mocked executable schema to Apollo Client?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

The Mocking example for Apollo GraphQL has the following code (see below).

The interesting thing is the last line - they create and execute the `graphql` query. But you usually need to create ApolloClient object. I can't figure out how to do that.

The ApolloClient expect the NetworkingInterface as an argument not the executable schema.

So, is there a way to create ApolloClient from the executable schema, without NetworkingInterface?

```js
import { makeExecutableSchema, addMockFunctionsToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { graphql } from 'graphql';

// Fill this in with the schema string
const schemaString = `...`;

// Make a GraphQL schema with no resolvers
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: schemaString });

// Add mocks, modifies schema in place
addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema });

const query = `
query tasksForUser {
  user(id: 6) { id, name }
}
`;

graphql(schema, query).then((result) => console.log('Got result', result));
```

Comment: There's an open PR to the docs that I still need to merge: https://github.com/apollographql/react-docs/pull/172

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is lifted from a [docs PR](https://github.com/apollographql/react-docs/pull/172) written by `magbicaleman` on GitHub, based on our [blog post](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/full-stack-react-graphql-tutorial-582ac8d24e3b):

You can easily do this with the `apollo-test-utils`, like so:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema, addMockFunctionsToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { mockNetworkInterfaceWithSchema } from 'apollo-test-utils';
import { typeDefs } from './schema';

// Create GraphQL schema object
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs });

// Add mocks
addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema });

// Create network interface
const mockNetworkInterface = mockNetworkInterfaceWithSchema({ schema });

// Initialize client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: mockNetworkInterface,
});
```

Now you can use the client instance as normal!

Comment: Ideally it should be something like `new ApolloClient({ schema: executableSchema })`

Comment: We aren't trying to optimize lines of code. In this case there is a specific method for each part of the process that does one thing well. You could easily write a helper function to make this one line if you wish!

Comment: It's not about lines of code but about the simplicity and ease of use.

Comment: This answer is only applicable for Apollo Client v1. In version 2, `networkInterface` has been replaced with `link`. More info here: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-test-utils/issues/39

Answer (score 6):

In Apollo client v2, `networkInterface` has been replaced with `link` for the network layer (see the client docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html#ApolloClient)).

`apollo-test-utils` hasn't been updated for Apollo client v2, and based on [conversations](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-test-utils/issues/39) from github, it seems the current recommendation is to use [`apollo-link-schema`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/schema.html):

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { SchemaLink } from 'apollo-link-schema';
import { makeExecutableSchema, addMockFunctionsToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { typeDefs } from './schema';

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs });
addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema });

const graphqlClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: new SchemaLink({ schema })
});
```

Then you just need to inject the client into whatever you're testing!